# Is the speed of opencv writing video slower than the actual setting speed？

Tags: opencv, video-capture

I want to use opencv to write a video file. When I set the frame rate to 20, the time to write each frame should be 50 ms, but when I get the time of writing each frame, there is a frame every 3 to 4 frames It took a lot of time, about 63 ms. This caused the video duration I wrote with opencv to be shorter than the actual recording duration.
My code is as follows

```
Mat frame;
VideoCapture cap(0, CAP_DSHOW);

cap.set(3, 640);
cap.set(4, 480);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 20);
VideoWriter video("test.avi", CV_FOURCC('X', 'V', 'I', 'D'), 20, Size(640, 480));

clock_t start, ends;
while (cap.isOpened()) {

    start = clock();

    cap >> frame;
    if (frame.empty()) break;
    video << frame;
    imshow("Frame1", frame);
    waitKey(1);
    if (_kbhit()) {
        int ch = _getch();
        if (ch == 27) break;
    }

    ends = clock();
    cout << ends - start << endl;

}
cap.release();
video.release();
destroyAllWindows();
```

The example of time to write each frame is 48 47 46 63 46 47 49 46 63 49 47 48 62 47 48 46 47 62 48 44 47 49 63 47 46 47 64，When I record a 5 min video, the actual video is only about 4 min 45 sec。
Thank you for your help。

Comment: video encoding is expensive. By telling to write 20 fps you just tell how the video has to be interpreted, it doesnt tell anything about how fast your system can encode/write frames. Get a faster PC and use buffering + threading and/or if you already have a hardware encoder (e.g. many intel CPUs) use a VideoWriter backend that allowe hardware accelerated encoding/writing (you'll have to google that)..

Comment: I will try it, thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

you're getting frames from a camera.

you did ask it for 20 fps but it might not be able to precisely do that.

it might also decide to give you fewer frames because it has to expose them longer because of low light compensation (if that is enabled).

some of your assumptions are simply invalid. I hope I managed to point them out to you.

if you "record a 5 minute video", you have kept secret how you do that, so we can't rely on your claim.

if there are questions left, you'll need to provide more information, such as precise number of frames over what period of time, and if this is demonstrable *without* also writing to a file while reading from the camera.

Comment: In fact, I wrote my local time on each frame of the picture. I just re-recorded a 606s video, but the video obtained is only 11758 frames, which is only 588s.

Comment: I use this code to get the time`timeb t;
 ftime(&t);
 tm* ltm = localtime(&t.time);
 time_str = to_string(1900 + ltm->tm_year) + " " + to_string(1 + ltm->tm_mon)\
  + " " + to_string(ltm->tm_mday) + " " + to_string(ltm->tm_hour) + ":" + \
  to_string(ltm->tm_min) + ":" + to_string(ltm->tm_sec) + "." + \
  to_string(t.millitm);`And use this code to write the time of each frame，`putText(frame, time_str, Point(100, 80), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2, 14, false)`     thank you for your reply